# WatchEventType.DELETE doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration-patterns

what I would like to do is to track the files removed and apply certain logic around this (get the id and update the entities). I've found that we can pass a list of watch events inside the channel adapter including

`FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.DELETE`

but when I remove the file from the folder I do not see any events triggered and the transformer is never being applied

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(FileToMovieTransformer fileToMovieTransformer) {

    return this.integrationFlowBuilder()
            .transform(fileToMovieTransformer)
            .channel(movieHandlerChannel())
            .get();

}

    private IntegrationFlowBuilder integrationFlowBuilder() {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(

            Files.inboundAdapter(new File(localFilmFolder))
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .useWatchService(true)
                    .watchEvents(FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE, FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.DELETE)
                    .patternFilter("*.xml"),

            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you treat `DELETE` wrong way:

```
/**
 * Directory entry deleted.
 *
 * <p> When a directory is registered for this event then the {@link WatchKey}
 * is queued when it is observed that an entry is deleted or renamed out of
 * the directory. The event {@link WatchEvent#count count} for this event
 * is always {@code 1}.
 */
public static final WatchEvent.Kind<Path> ENTRY_DELETE =
    new StdWatchEventKind<Path>("ENTRY_DELETE", Path.class);
```

So, there is already nothing to emit as a message to downstream. We definitely talk here about a `FileReadingMessageSource`. But with `DELETE` there is nothing to read any more. Am I missing anything?

And here is what we have in the Docs so far:

> The `ENTRY_DELETE` events have effect for the `ResettableFileListFilter` implementations and, therefore, their files
>   are provided for the `remove()` operation.
>   This means that (when this event is enabled), filters such as the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` will have the file removed,
>   meaning that, if a file with the same name appears, it will pass the filter and be sent as a message.

Therefore to achieve whatever you would like to do in case of `DELETE` event, you need to implement `ResettableFileListFilter` and together with `SimplePatternFileListFilter` you should composite them into the `CompositeFileListFilter`.

When file is deleted , that `DELETE` event is emitted and we end up with the logic like:

```
if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
    if (getFilter() instanceof ResettableFileListFilter) {
        ((ResettableFileListFilter<File>) getFilter()).remove(file);
    }
```

Where the mentioned `CompositeFileListFilter` definitely implements this `ResettableFileListFilter` one and will delegate to your own implementation.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation, clear enough, except the way to expand the composite filter with my new implementation of the ResettableFileListFilter without having any effect on the pattern i use .patternFilter("*.xml") an example or any references will be very much appreciated?

Comment: There is a `.filter()` for the `Files.inboundAdapter()` option instead of the mentioned `.patternFilter("*.xml")`. That's where you will inject that `CompositeFileListFilter`. The `.patternFilter("*.xml")` will go in this case to the `SimplePatternFileListFilter`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

Comment: thanks, got it completely, very useful will post code when check it out

Answer (score 1):

thanks for @Artem, here is the complete code sample that seems to work well for me

```
    private IntegrationFlowBuilder integrationFlowBuilder() {

    final List<FileListFilter<File>> defaultFilters = new ArrayList<>(2);

    defaultFilters.add(new IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter());
    defaultFilters.add(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
    defaultFilters.add(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
    defaultFilters.add(myCustomRemovalFilter);

    CompositeFileListFilter fileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>(defaultFilters);

    return IntegrationFlows.from(

            Files.inboundAdapter(new File(localFilmFolder))
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .filter(fileListFilter)
                    .useWatchService(true)
                    .watchEvents(FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE, FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.DELETE),

            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            ));
}
```

and the filter looks like

```
@Component
public class MyCustomRemovalFilter implements ResettableFileListFilter<File> {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyCustomRemovalFilter.class);

@Override
public boolean remove(File xmlFile) {

    if (xmlFile == null) {
        return true;
    }
    // TODO you own on removal logic 
}

@Override
public List<File> filterFiles(File[] files) {

    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return Arrays.asList(files);
}
}
```